Website from zip file renderer - problems with nested dependencies from blob
I have been working on a solution to render a webpage (with dependencies etc) from a zip file.
I have gotten sofar that it renders most things relatively well,
But inline scripts that fetch yet other content (f.e. jquery document load html, which loads yet another local file) still throw ERR_FILE_NOT Found.
Sofar this is my effort:
https://codepen.io/ryedai1/pen/jOjNjVR
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JSZip Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.7.1/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    if (typeof JSZip === 'undefined') {
      document.write('<script src="jszip.min.js"><\/script>');
    }
    
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async function () {
      const url = "https://alcea-wisteria.de/z_files/alceawis.de.zip";
      const fileListElement = document.getElementById("file-list");

      function sanitizeFileName(fileName) {
        return fileName.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]/g, '_');
      }

      async function getFileType(fileName) {
        const extension = fileName.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        switch (extension) {
          case 'html':
          case 'htm':
            return 'text/html';
          case 'css':
            return 'text/css';
          case 'js':
            return 'application/javascript';
          case 'json':
            return 'application/json';
          case 'png':
            return 'image/png';
          case 'jpg':
          case 'jpeg':
            return 'image/jpeg';
          case 'gif':
            return 'image/gif';
          case 'svg':
            return 'image/svg+xml';
          default:
            return 'application/octet-stream';
        }
      }

      async function processScriptContent(content, fileMap) {
        fileMap.forEach(({ relativePath, absolutePath }) => {
          const regex = new RegExp(relativePath.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'), 'g');
          content = content.replace(regex, absolutePath);
        });

        content = content.replace(/fetch\(['"]([^'"]+)['"]\)/g, (match, p1) => {
          const file = fileMap.find(entry => entry.relativePath === p1);
          if (file) {
            return `fetch('${file.absolutePath}')`;
          } else {
            return match;
          }
        });

        content = content.replace(/['"]([^'"]+\.(json|xml|csv|txt|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg))['"]/g, (match, p1) => {
          const file = fileMap.find(entry => entry.relativePath === p1);
          if (file) {
            return `'${file.absolutePath}'`;
          } else {
            return match;
          }
        });

        return content;
      }

      async function loadHtmlContent(content, fileMap) {
        let modifiedContent = content;
        fileMap.forEach(({ relativePath, absolutePath }) => {
          const regex = new RegExp(relativePath.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'), 'g');
          modifiedContent = modifiedContent.replace(regex, absolutePath);
        });

        const tempElement = document.createElement('div');
        tempElement.innerHTML = modifiedContent;

        tempElement.querySelectorAll('iframe').forEach(iframe => {
          const src = iframe.getAttribute('src');
          const file = fileMap.find(entry => entry.relativePath === src);
          if (file) {
            iframe.setAttribute('src', file.absolutePath);
          }
        });

        tempElement.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(anchor => {
          const href = anchor.getAttribute('href');
          if (href && !href.startsWith('http')) {
            const file = fileMap.find(entry => entry.relativePath === href);
            if (file) {
              anchor.setAttribute('href', file.absolutePath);
              anchor.setAttribute('target', '_self');
            }
          }
        });

        const scriptPromises = [];
        tempElement.querySelectorAll('script').forEach(script => {
          const src = script.getAttribute('src');
          if (src) {
            const file = fileMap.find(entry => entry.relativePath === src);
            if (file) {
              const newScript = document.createElement('script');
              newScript.src = file.absolutePath;
              newScript.type = 'application/javascript';
              script.replaceWith(newScript);
            }
          } else {
            scriptPromises.push(new Promise(async (resolve) => {
              const scriptContent = await processScriptContent(script.textContent, fileMap);
              const newScript = document.createElement('script');
              newScript.textContent = scriptContent;
              script.replaceWith(newScript);
              resolve();
            }));
          }
        });

        await Promise.all(scriptPromises);

        document.open();
        document.write(tempElement.innerHTML);
        document.close();
      }

      try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        if (!response.ok) throw new Error("Failed to fetch the zip file.");

        const blob = await response.blob();
        const zip = await JSZip.loadAsync(blob);

        const fileMap = [];
        for (const [relativePath, file] of Object.entries(zip.files)) {
          if (!file.dir) {
            const fileContent = await file.async("blob");
            const fileType = await getFileType(relativePath);
            const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([fileContent], { type: fileType }));
            fileMap.push({ relativePath, absolutePath: objectUrl });
          }
        }

        fileListElement.textContent = fileMap.map(entry => entry.relativePath).join("\n");

        const indexPath = "index.html";
        const indexFile = fileMap.find(entry => entry.relativePath === indexPath);
        if (indexFile) {
          try {
            const response = await fetch(indexFile.absolutePath);
            const indexContent = await response.text();
            await loadHtmlContent(indexContent, fileMap);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error loading ${indexPath} from object URL. Trying to load from zip blob.`);
            console.error(error);
            console.log(`Refetching ${indexFile.relativePath} from zip blob.`);
            const indexContent = await indexFile.blob();
            const textContent = await new Response(indexContent).text();
            await loadHtmlContent(textContent, fileMap);
          }
        } else {
          throw new Error(`${indexPath} not found in the zip file.`);
        }

      } catch (error) {
        fileListElement.textContent = "Error: " + error.message;
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>JSZip Example</h1>
  <pre id="file-list"></pre>
</body>
</html>


Any help is appreciated
PS:
In the link ther is a"take1".
I used a different approach before, which handles dpendencies far better, but it kind of weird to apply to the current approach.
I also considered using service-worker(s), but lack the experience with them.
I tried to implement a fallback mechanism to redirect ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND to the zip blob.
Sadly to no avail
